# Select text within terminal output using VIM

Tags: linux, vim, command-line, terminal, xfce

Let's say I have the following output in my terminal window now:

```
1. vsud@vsud:~$ pwd
2. /home/vsud
3. vsud@vsud:~$ echo "Hello, world!"
4. Hello, world!
```

I want to copy to clipboard the 1st and 2nd lines.

```
vsud@vsud:~$ pwd
/home/vsud
```

With mouse - I can do that by selecting those 2 lines and pressing Ctrl + Shift + C.
But can I enter into VIM mode somehow and work with that whole output in my terminal as with pure text - so to copy 2 lines I will need to type just "H2yy" ?
Do I need to install some specific Terminal Emulator for that?

Now I'm using terminal emulator which is built in XFCE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to do that: (1) Using tmux, and using (2) ':term' inside vim

**tmux**

If you are using your terminal from within tmux, you can enter *copy mode* and select and copy lines from your terminal. Assuming tmux Prefix is Ctrl-b, the precise steps to do this are:

1. Enter *copy mode*: Ctrl-b [
2. Start selecting: Space
3. Extend selection: use arrow keys
4. Store selection in buffer: Enter
5. Transfer selection to system clipboard: Ctrl-b : run-shell "tmux save buffer - | xsel -i -b"
6. Paste the selection into a vim buffer(+ register): "+p

*Additional Notes:*

a. tmux offers a command called "capture-pane", with which you can copy an entire pane(terminal).

b. You need xsel to be installed for step 5 above to work. Step 5 can be shortened by using a keybinding. For that have the following command in your .tmux.conf (or, entering this command on your tmux command line `Ctrl-b :`)

`bind C-c run-shell "tmux save-buffer - | xsel -i -b"`

Now step 5 is equivalent to pressing Ctrl-c.

c. You can use vim keys for navigation in copy mode: Ctrl-b :setw -g mode-keys vi

**:term**

If you fire terminal from inside vim using the ex command ':term', you can enter "normal" mode using: Ctrl-W Shift-n. Then you can navigate (and copy in) the terminal with vim keys as if it were a regular vim buffer.

Comment: Thank you! Using terminal within vim by `:term` seams the easiest way - will use that!

Comment: is there also a way to be able to select, copy and paste text inside vim's :term terminal? After yanking the selection it's not possible to paste into terminal...

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe the output to vim using `view -`. For example:

```sh
ls -la | view -
```

This opens a vim instance in read-only mode which can read from `stdin`

Comment: well - but that can only read the output of some single command.
I would like to work with the entire terminal buffer (let's say 2k lines) as a big text document in vim - and easily navigate through outputs of previous commands too.